# Is algebraic dependence a transitive relation?

Tags: irrational-numbers, algebraic-independence

If $\{x,y\}$ and $\{y,z\}$ are both [algebraically dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence), then is also $\{x,z\}$ algebraically dependent?

The important thing is: if they are, then algebraic dependence is an equivalence relation (because reflexivity and simmetry are trivially true).

If yes, do their equivalence classes have some special meaning or parametrization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are referring to elements of a common field $F\supseteq k(x,y,z)$ and algebraic dependence is over some fixed subfield $k$, then yes, because \begin{align}[k(x,z):k(x)]\le& [k(x,y,z):k(x)]=[k(x,y,z):k(x,y)][k(x,y):k(x)]\le\\\le& [k(z,y):k(y)][k(x,y):k(x)]\end{align}

Where $[k(z,y):k(y)]\ge [k(x,y,z):k(x,y)]$ because if $f\in k(y)[T]$ is a primitive polynomial for $z$ over $k(y)$, then $f\in k(x,y)[T]$ in the obvious way and it's a fortiori a multiple of some primitive polynomial for $z$ over $k(x,y)$.

When $x$ isn't algebraically dependent with $0$ over $k$, the equivalence class of the elements of $F$ that are algebraically dependent with $x$ is the subfield of the elements of $F$ that are algebraic over $k(x)$, minus the subfield of the elements of $F$ that are algebraic over $k$. The class of $0$ is the subfield of the elements of $F$ that are algebraic over $k$.

Comment: It was not easy to decode, what do you understand on $k(x,...)$. But finally I investigated it. :-) It is a field of k, extended with x,... . Sad that I had no way to learn such higher group theoretic math.

Comment: @peterh Ah, ok I guess in your case, of all this machinery, $k=\Bbb Q$ and $F=\Bbb C$ will do. Then $\Bbb Q(a_i\,:\, i\in I)$ will then be the smallest subfield of $\Bbb C$ containing $\Bbb Q$ and all the $a_i$-s and, given a subfield $K\subseteq \Bbb C$, $K[T]$ is the set of polynomials in the variable $T$ with coefficients in $K$. Given two subfields $K\subseteq L$, $[L:K]$ is the dimension of $L$ as a $K$-vector space.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If there would be some parametrization of the equilance classes, and there would be "easily" way ("easy" means here: the best mathematicians of the world can calculate it) to calculate for a specific transcendent number, then it would be a way to prove the algebraic independence of two specific irrational numbers. So, for example, the irrationality of $e+\pi$ could be proven.

Comment: @peterh Which indicates that it isn't a simple feat, and possibly an impossibile one.

Comment: But if $y=0$ and $x$ is anything, then the polynomial $P(U,V)=U$ is nonzero and defined on the base field, and vanishes at $(y,x)$. According to the Wikipedia definition, this means that $\{y,x\}$ is algebraically dependent, no?

Comment: @Mindlack Oh, damn... you're right (and perhaps you even were before). For some reason I was thinking about the relation $$x\sim y\Leftrightarrow x\text{ algebraic over }k(y)$$ instead of $$x\sim y\Leftrightarrow \operatorname{trdeg}_k k(x,y)<2$$

Comment: Also, if we want to stick to what the OP wrote, then the relation of $\{x,y\}$ being algebraically dependent may not be reflexive, because for $x$ trascendental $\{x,x\}=\{x\}$ is algebraically independent. Since it's symmetric, it can't be transitive.

Comment: But if I'm using mine, then the relation *is* transitive, *but* it isn't symmetric... And that's why that last part looked suspicious! @Mindlack

Comment: @peterh Could you please un-accept my answer so that I can delete it?

Comment: @Gae.S. Both the answer and the comments look to me very valuable. Why do you want to delete it? If there was some mistake, just insert a correction. You deserve the +25. I will unaccept if you really want to, but I don't think that it is a good idea.

Comment: @Gae.S. Btw, for $\{x,x\}$, trivially can we generaty 2-variable polynomes for which the result is zero. It is like that two equal vectors are parallel to each other. Ok, $\{x,x\}$ is a set, so $\{x,x\} = \{x\}$. Maybe the definition is buggy.

Comment: @Gae.S. Afaik, rigorously interpreted, not even vector parallelism is an equivalence relation. Because the null-vector is parallel with all vectors. But it is an equivalence relation in the non-zero vectors. Isn't the case some similar in the algebraic dependence?